# Why does my Django form not work on submit?

Tags: django

So I'm using `modelformset_factory`, and my template renders it perfectly but submit button won't work. Let me show you my code:
forms.py

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer = forms.CharField(required=False)
    share_to_others = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
from .models import Answer
from .forms import AnswerForm

def createAnswer(request, pk):
    AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Answer, form=AnswerForm, extra=1)
    formset = AnswerFormSet(
        queryset=Answer.objects.filter(authuser=request.user.id, question_number=pk)
    )

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            instance = formset.save(commit=False)
            instance[0].authuser = request.user
            instance[0].question_number = thisQuestion
            instance[0].save()

        return redirect('/main')
    context = {
        'formset':formset,
    }
    return render(request, '/answerPage.html', context)
```

and my template

```
...
<form method="POST" class="form-group">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {% crispy formset %}
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I don't see what I have done wrong. When I click the submit button, nothing happens and the page stays still. Any help is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: maybe, `form method="post"` instead of `form method="POST"`

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: you're missing action form attribute that should point to your django registered url

Comment: @ihoryam I've tried it, but it's still the same. Thanks though :)